# top five dict from list of dict sort by dict value

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

i have list of dict below
[{'balance': '4560.00', 'totalinwardqty': '4600.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '40.00', 'srno': 1, 'productname': u'mobile'},
 {'balance': '310.00', 'totalinwardqty': '600.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '290.00', 'srno': 2, 'productname': u'laptop'},
 {'balance': '30.00', 'totalinwardqty': '502.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '472.00', 'srno': 3, 'productname': u'AC'},
 {'balance': '654.00', 'totalinwardqty': '749.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '95.00', 'srno': 4, 'productname': u'car'},
 {'balance': '100.00', 'totalinwardqty': '100.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '0.00', 'srno': 5, 'productname': u'tab'},
{'balance': '6000.00', 'totalinwardqty': '6000.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '0.00', 'srno': 6, 'productname': u'ram'},
 {'balance': '500.00', 'totalinwardqty': '500.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '0.00', 'srno': 7, 'productname': u'arduino'},
 {'balance': '80.00', 'totalinwardqty': '80.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '0.00', 'srno': 8, 'productname': u'wifi module'}]

i want top five list of dict which is sort by totaloutwardqty in ascending  order

Answer (score 0):

first, store your list in a variable:

```
lst =  [{'balance': '4560.00', 'totalinwardqty': '4600.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '40.00', 'srno': 1, 'productname': u'mobile'},
{'balance': '310.00', 'totalinwardqty': '600.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '290.00', 'srno': 2, 'productname': u'laptop'},
{'balance': '30.00', 'totalinwardqty': '502.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '472.00', 'srno': 3, 'productname': u'AC'},
{'balance': '654.00', 'totalinwardqty': '749.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '95.00', 'srno': 4, 'productname': u'car'},
{'balance': '100.00', 'totalinwardqty': '100.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '0.00', 'srno': 5, 'productname': u'tab'},
{'balance': '6000.00', 'totalinwardqty': '6000.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '0.00', 'srno': 6, 'productname': u'ram'},
{'balance': '500.00', 'totalinwardqty': '500.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '0.00', 'srno': 7, 'productname': u'arduino'},
{'balance': '80.00', 'totalinwardqty': '80.00', 'totaloutwardqty': '0.00', 'srno': 8, 'productname': u'wifi module'}]
```

then use `sorted`.
with top 5 in ascending order i assume you mean the lowest 5 by totaloutwardqty.

```
sorted(lst,key =lambda x: float(x['totaloutwardqty']))[0:5]
```

for descending order:

```
sorted(lst,key =lambda x: -1*float(x['totaloutwardqty']))[0:5]
```